# How to sum top results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm wondering how one would sum the results from a query?

I want to know how many people live in total in the three biggest cities in Norway. I'm using mysql, the world.sql sample database in mysql workbench.

This is the closest I've gotten

```
SELECT population
FROM city 
WHERE CountryCode = 'NOR' 
ORDER BY population DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

There's a few problems here namely this gives me three results instead of one, and while using LIMIT which actually limits how many results it gives, not how many it uses.

Any ideas?

Comment: using `sum(population)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(population)
FROM (SELECT population
      FROM city 
      WHERE CountryCode = 'NOR' 
      ORDER BY population DESC 
      LIMIT 3
     ) cp
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

simply sum the result:

```
select  sum(population) from (SELECT population
FROM city 
WHERE CountryCode = 'NOR' 
ORDER BY population DESC 
LIMIT 3) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

> select sum(population)  from  (SELECT population FROM city  WHERE 
>   CountryCode = 'NOR'  ORDER BY population DESC  LIMIT 3) temp

Comment: This will not get the correct result. You will get the sum population of all cities

Answer (score 0):

Read on subqueries.
Make your current query a subquery and get `sum` from your subquery.

```
SELECT SUM(population) FROM (
SELECT population
FROM city 
WHERE CountryCode = 'NOR' 
ORDER BY population DESC 
LIMIT 3) p
```

You query will now act as a virtual table, from which you can you can write a `select` query to get the sum